# Java matcher doesn't return the waited values and groups

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code

```
String regexString = "[^']*'(\\w+)'[^']*'(\\w+)'";
message = "Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'username'";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
if (matcher.mathces()){
    String key = matcher.group(2);
    String value = matcher.group(1);
}
```

while value variable gets the correct value from message (admin) key instead of getting the value username it stores the whole message. Running my message and regex on online regex editors gives me the correct values like [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). Am I missing something?

Comment: Works for me like a charm. although you misspelled `matcher.mathces()` ;-)

Comment: I would use `"[^']*'([^']+)'[^']*'([^']+)'"` to have a matcher without lookahead, but your version should work fine too!

Comment: Maybe the original code mixed up vars/fields, an other Matcher/Pattern/Message. Or the message ends in a space or period (`\r`?).

Comment: The message comes from an Throwable's getMessage() method. No no period. Debugger shows exactly what I have written you `"Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'username'"` . Not really sure.

Comment: What is actual and expected behaviour? What are you trying to do? It's unclear what you are asking.